# SQL Server pivots? some way to set column names to values within a row

Tags: sql, dynamic, row, pivot

I am building a system of multiple trackers that are going to use a lot of the same columns so there is a table for the trackers, the tracker columns, then a cross reference for which columns go with which tracker, when a user inserts a tracker row the different column values are stored in multiple rows that share the same record id and store both the value and the name of the particular column.

I need to find a way to dynamically change the column name of the value to be the column name that is stored in the same row.

i.e.

```
id | value | name
------------------
23 | red   | color
23 | fast  | speed
```

needs to look like this.

```
id | color | speed
------------------
23 | red   | fast
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: SQL is not designed for this kind of transposition, you should delegate this operation to your application layer.

Comment: @OlivierCoilland: PIVOT syntax is ANSI (99 I believe).  SQL Server has supported the function since v2005

Comment: Consider that you have a theoretically-infinite amount of columns which could be generated in this way....

Answer (score 10):

You can perform this type of query with a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). There are two ways, a static pivot where you hard-code the values of the columns or a dynamic pivot where the columns are determined at run-time.

**Static Pivot** (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aeec6/1))

```
select *
from 
(
  select id, value, name
  from test
) x
pivot
(
  min(value)
  for name in ([color], [speed])
) p
```

**Dynamic Pivot** (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7ffa/1))

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from test
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
      = 'SELECT id,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            SELECT id, value, name
            FROM test
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            min(value)
            for name in (' + @cols + ')
         ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Both queries will produce the same results. The difference is that in the first you have to code all of the values that you want to become columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to post. Worked a treat for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Column names are *always* static in SQL Server. You can generate dynamic SQL though.

Comment: I found a way to do it using PIVOT the only problem is I have to define the names of the columns in the proc but it does combine all of the values appropriately into one row grouped by the ID

Comment: Yes. Pivot can do that, but still the column names are static. You cannot make them depend on database contents.