# Best way to include a dynamic number of related table rows as columns in an SQL result set

Tags: sql

I have three tables with data like this:

An `item` table that contains basic info per item.  Each item has one 'template' that determines a set of meta data for items with that template.

```
id | name   | template_id
--------------------------
 1 | Thing1 | t1
 2 | Thing2 | t2
```

A `template_fields` table that contains a row for each type of meta data that could be associated with an item with particular template.  It looks something like the table below.  Here there are two templates, one with two fields and one with a single field. (The number of fields can vary per template.)

```
 id | key   | order
--------------------
 t1 | color | 1
 t1 | size  | 2
 t2 | year  | 1
```

Finally, there is a `meta_data` table that contains the actual values associated with the template fields for each item:

```
item_id | template_id | key   | value
--------------------------------------
 1      | t1          | color | Red
 1      | t1          | size  | 2
 2      | t2          | year  | 2014
```

Now, in my application I want to have a per-template view of this data so that if I want to see  items of template a particular template each row in the result set contains a column for each field in the corresponding template.  For example, items in template t1 would look like this:

```
item_id | name   | color | size
--------------------------------
1       | Thing1 | Red   | 2
```

Similarly for items in template t2

```
item_id | name   | year 
------------------------
1       | Thing2 | 2014
```

Is there a way to do this in a single SQL query?  (Keep in mind that I do not know the number of fields in a template until runtime.  I am also not concerned with having a view that contains fields from items with different templates; one template at a time.)

My best whack at a solution so far is something like the pseudo code below, but please let me know if you think there is a better way (including a better table structure) to accomplish what I want.

```
fields = SELECT template_fields.key, meta_data.value FROM template_fields 
    JOIN meta_data ON 
        meta_data.template_id = template_fields.id 
        AND meta_data.key = template_fields.key
    WHERE meta_data.item_id IN (SELECT id FROM item WHERE template='t1')
    ORDER BY meta_data.item_id, template_fields.order

items = SELECT * FROM item WHERE template='t1'

i = 0
for item in items:
    while fields[i].item_id = item.id:
        item[fields[i].key] = fields[i].value
        i += 1
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f566f/1/0) to play with

Comment: What you are looking for is called `EAV-Pattern`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model. However this pattern has many drawbacks, when it comes down to searching or sorting, cause you cannot use *native* SQL-Commands to achieve that. Especially, when you want to transform the *value* table to real columns (most likely to perform sorting or searching) you will have performance issues cause EVERY column is an additional join and you need to use some aggregation methods to eliminate *null*-values. (Known as the "Max-Hack")

Comment: This might give you an idea -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300428/sql-server-pivots-some-way-to-set-column-names-to-values-within-a-row